# How to set two keybinds in c# that would show and hide a form?

Tags: c#

I've seen this done in a different program where <kbd>F6</kbd> was set to hide the form and <kbd>F7</kbd> would then show the form again. I would like to implement this feature into my basic program and just know how to recreate it in general.

**Psuedocode**

```
if KeyM Pressed
{
    Hide Form1
}
if KeyN Pressed
{
    Show Form1
}
```

There is also only one form.

Comment: You may need to use the Windows API to define global hotkeys.
Or if you only want to hide/show another form if one form is active, then you can do it in `KeyDown` of the active form

Answer (score 0):

You can hide and show a form from other form:
Form 1 and Form2, add KeyDown event to Form1 like this:

```
if (e.KeyCode == Keys.F6 && e.Modifiers == Keys.Control)
        {
            f.Hide();
        }
        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.F7 && e.Modifiers == Keys.Control)
        {

            f.Show();
        }
```

or f is Form2 instance declared golbal in Form1
and set the attribute KeyPreview of Form1 true